# EF 6.1.3 Lazy loading not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading

I am trying to get a single employee record, but looking at the Diagnostic Tools it is showing Entity Framework performing tons of queries loading the entire database.  Lazy loading is enabled and I am using the `public` and `virtual` keywords so I don't think that should be the problem.  Is there anything I am missing, the navigational properties for the `Employee` record should not be loading.

Service:

```
return _employeeRepo.GetEmployee(sid);
```

Repository:

```
public Employee GetEmployee(string sid)
    {
        Employee employee = Context.Employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.SID == sid);

        return employee != null ? employee.ToDomain() : null;
    }
```

Employee Model:

```
public class Employee
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Disability> Disabilities { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Bureau Bureau { get; set; }
    public virtual Division Division { get; set; }
    ...

    public Domain.Models.Employee ToDomain()
    {
        return Mapper.Map<Domain.Models.Employee>(this);
    }
}
```

Context:

```
public class SqlContext : DbContext
{
    public SqlContext() : base("SqlContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<SqlContext>(null);
    }

    public virtual DbSet<EfModels.Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EfModels.Bureau> Bureaus { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EfModels.Disability> Disabilities { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EfModels.Division> Divisions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EfModels.Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Employee.ToDomain() Can you show this extension method?

Comment: I added it to the Employee Model.  I have an `Employee` model in the data access layer (shown above) and an `Employee` record in the `Domain` layer.  All it does is map the data model to the Domain model.

Comment: Yes, But is it mapping too tables that are related to the Employee Entity to get all of the information?

Comment: Yeah, you're correct.  I set a breakpoint and when it hits the `return employee != null ? employee.ToDomain() : null` line that is where it starts hitting all of those queries.  Should I change it for `AutoMapper` to not map to all of the related tables (if that's even possible)?

Comment: Im not versed with automapper, cant help you with that. You shouldnt need to use automapper, its a nice tool, but you should be able to map form one type to another, without using it. SHow your code for mapping please?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll do some research with it.  The `ToDomain()` method is all of the code for mapping.  `AutoMapper` does the rest behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Mapping Tool (AutoMapper) is the issue.

When your calling employee.ToDomain(), the navigation properties of your entity are being accessed, causing EF to lazy load the tables.